# Complex LINQ SelectMany

Tags: linq

I have a number of tables I need to join. Tables x,b,c join normally and I'll call that J1.
Tables x,d are another normal join that I call J2.

Now I need to join J1 and J2 together. For every row in J1 there may be multiple related rows in J2. Table x has a date field among other conditions (which are easy to set up and are in the group join), but I need to get the latest/highest J2 row. Table x has a date field, and basically for every row in J1 I can have multiple rows in J2, and I need to get the most recent one.

I have the joins for J1 in place. The join for J2 is also in place, as first element in a GroupJoin on J1.

Where I am totally lost are two issues:

- At one point I need to filter out by date. J1*x x entry must be later
  than J1's (there can be older ones).
- The Select Many needs to take the most recent one, which would implicate some ordering, but I have not been successful at adding a sort. Where do I put that in? I have the GroupJoin, followed by the SelectMany. Where do I put in the OrderBy?

Note I require lambda syntax; I can not rewrite it to another form.

Help is appreciated

Comment: Please fix the typos in your question.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear at the moment, mostly because it's rather abstract. If you could give a *concrete* example of what you're trying to do, that would really help. Also, if the first join is irrelevant, it would be worth removing that from the equation.

Comment: I know. It is quite abstarct. Sadly the query itself spans like two pages by now. Tehe join between innner and outer join has about a dozen fixed conditions. It is not irrelevant, btw... Basically, J1 has data, J2 has some additional data that MAY be there for every item in J1, and if it is there we need the latest most up to date version.

Answer (score 0):

**Conditions:**

1) J1 (Single line)(x,b,c)  = J2 (Multiple line) (x,d)

2) J2.x has datefield for ordering

3) J2.x entry must be later than J1.x

4) J2.x filter out by date

if its correct

Comment: Pretty much. J1 has data, J2 MAY have additional data, and MAY have multiple items, whichis when I need * Data in J2 more current and if multiple the most current.